# What is the probability of drawing a hearts when the first card you draw was spade? Please check the description

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Intuitively we know that when the first card drawn was Spade, it left $13$ hearts and $51$ cards so the probability is $13/51$.

I was trying to solve it by the formula of conditional probability P(B|A) = (JOINT PROBABILITY OF A AND B) / PROBABILITY OF A.

- Joint probability of A and B will be $\dfrac{{13\choose 1} \times {13\choose 1} }{{52\choose 2} }$.
- Probability of A is $1/4$
- Dividing these two gives the result as $26/51$ .

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what (13C113C1)/52C2 means, can you be clearer about that?

Comment: @kviiri Presumably $\dfrac{{13\choose 1} \times {13\choose 1} }{{52\choose 2} }$

Answer (score 3):

The joint probability of A *then* B is $\dfrac{13}{52} \times \dfrac{13}{ 51}$

Your expression of $\dfrac{{13\choose 1} \times {13\choose 1} }{{52\choose 2} }$ is the probability of A then B *or* B then A, and so is double the value you want here.